# iPhone case material for best heat dissipation?

Tags: iphone, case

What case material for iPhone is most effective at dissipating heat. With my current case, my iPhone 11 often feels hot at the bottom of the screen but cools down when I take the case off, so I am confident that the case causes some heat to linger around. I was wondering which material will be best at dissipating heat and if you have any recommendations? TPU, rubber, plastic, metal, silicone, etc?

*This is not a shopping recommendation question, rather a material specific question.*

Answer (score 1):

You can simply take a physics data book and lookup various materials to see how conductive they are.

Of the ones you list, metal is going to be the most efficient. For example in computers, heat sinks are often made of aluminium.

Note that there usually other properties to take into account when buying a phone case. For example it's hard to find transparent and very flexible metal (i.e. something that will allow you to bend the case slightly to allow you to put in the phone, but won't permanently deform the case).

In some cases those properties can mean that the phone won't be usable for you. For example, I know that you can buy cases with backs made of brushed steel. They are good at heat dissipation, they're flexible for you to put the phone into them easily - but the problem is they also block cell reception and WiFi signals.

Answer (score 1):

The best material for heat dissipation is going to be copper.  The problem is, it’s a soft metal that’s very malleable meaning it’ll deform quite easily.

Next in line is aluminum, but it too, is a malleable material that will deform quite easily.

The down side to these conductive materials is that it conducts heat from *all* sources.  In other words, leave your aluminum encased phone out in the sun and it will cook.

Your phone is going to generate heat, both from the chemical reaction within the battery and the fact you’re moving electrons around the circuitry.

Lithium ion batteries have an [operating threshold](https://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/charging_at_high_and_low_temperatures) of between -20C and 65C (-4F and 140F). In other words, it functions in environments most humans can’t survive in.  Your [iPhone doesn’t operate in anywhere near this environment](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP805?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) - 0C to 35C (32F to 95F).  It will thermally shut down to protect itself if it gets too hot.

If you can hold it, it’s fine.  If it’s hot enough that you suffer actual burns, there’s a problem and you need to take it in for service.  As far as a case goes, get one that protects your phone and is aesthetically pleasing to you.

Comment: I agree that a case isn't going to do much for the OP. However, if you _could_ find a way to keep the phone substantially cooler, there is reason to believe it could have a measurable performance impact. Take a look at the result of using this ridiculous water cooler with an Android phone: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F91bGJBQLFc

Comment: @Wowfunhappy - I guess you’d have to have a permanent Big Gulp cup with you at all times.  But I did lol when I saw the coolers were made of....copper!  